# PHP wont insert html tags into database

Tags: php

PHP won't let me insert my username field into the database for some reason:

```
$username = "<a href='user.php?user=".$_SESSION['username']."'>@".$_SESSION['username']."<a>";

/* Query database to save user's post */
/* If field "repostid==0", then the post is not a repost; if the field "repostid>0", then the post is a repost with the field "repostid" linking to the id of the post to be reposted */ 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO posts (user, content, repostid, date) VALUES ('$username', '$final_repostinfo', '$_GET[postid]', '$date_string')");
if (!$result)
{
    die('Cannot query. Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

The returned PHP syntax error:

```
Cannot query. Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user.php?user=shawn619'>@shawn619', 'fifth', '8', '01/12/2013 21:38:56')' at line 1
```

Comment: Use prepared/parameterized queries to solve this problem, and many others you likely have at the moment.

Comment: It's an assignment so i can't use prepared statements

Comment: You are being taught incorrectly.  Prepared/parameterized queries are the only way you should be using arbitrary data in a DB query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because of the single quotes.  Try:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO posts (user, content, repostid, date) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."', '$final_repostinfo', '$_GET[postid]', '$date_string')");
```

Or

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO posts (user, content, repostid, date) VALUES ('".add_slashes($username)."', '$final_repostinfo', '$_GET[postid]', '$date_string')");
```

Comment: No way man, you would escape one variable but leave `$_GET['postid']` out there?  Escape everything!

Comment: @Brad lmao, that wasn't the question though.  I've only answered the question.  So you downvoted for that?  Nice.

Comment: Absolutely I downvoted you for that.  Your code is broken.  Do you realize how many **thousands** of folks out there that blindly copy/paste stuff they see on Stack Overflow?  They work at schools teaching others bad code who go on to work for banks which fund money to hire thousands of bad programmers getting defense contracts.  If you see a problem, call attention to it and fix it.  Otherwise, your answer is, in my opinion, incomplete.

Comment: @Brad I agree that people copy/paste bad code all the time.  However, the question specifically talked about the HTML code.  I answered the question.  The fact that I didn't worry about also informing them that they need to escape all of their user inputs correctly may deserve a comment, but not a down vote.  I gave no false information and answered the question correctly. This just seems like trolling to me.

Comment: Trolling for what?  Your answer is broken, and not just for security reasons.  If someone posts bad code here, we vote it down or edit to improve it.

Comment: @Brad The code is not broken.  How do you know that they did not do something similar to `$_GET['postid'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['postid']);` prior to the code they shared?  You are making assumptions just to make assumptions.  That's not helpful.

Comment: It's a pretty safe assumption that when you see a request variable left in a URL with no escaping, while there is escaping cancatenated in for other variables, that you missed something.  If anything, it smells terrible and should be investigated.  Also, your suggestion of using `add_slashes()` is ridiculous, and will not work to prevent any SQL injection.

Comment: @Brad `add_slashes()` still fixes his particular issue for the html.  My answer is legit.  And I do the same thing in my code with `$_POST` variables.  I have a function that cleans the array and returns it back still within the `$_POST` variable.  Again, I would agree that it deserves a comment or edit, but not a downvote.

Comment: You should post this vacuum cleaner class in a Gist somewhere.  I'd love to read it.  If you're escaping data for use in SQL query much before you actually run the query, you are most likely escaping your data far too early, making it useless for other purposes.  This is all solved completely with prepared/parameterized queries.

Comment: Actually, James' 1st solution did solve my question, so i have to side with him. Good day, thanks James.

Comment: @shawna Your house is on fire.  James showed up with a gallon of water and watered your garden.  I told you where to find the fire department.  Do what you want.

Comment: @shawna I'm glad it helped.  :)  If my answer fixed your issue, please remember to mark it as the answer.  On a side note, Brad is right that you do need to make sure you scrub any user input before using it in your query string.  However, I was only answering the question asked in your post, so I'm not sure what his issue was with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by **separating the html markup.**
I had a similar problem when trying to insert html markup into a database.
Leave $username as being just $_SESSION['username'], then when you need to retrieve the value from the database THAT'S when you add the html markup. 
For example, I was trying to cut corners by having the markup entered into the database, rather than putting it where it needs to be used.

I had the following PHP code:

```
$image = "<img src='".$_FILES['image']['name']."' />";
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES (CURRENT_DATE,'$image')");
```

Then in the page I was using to retrieve data from the database:

```
echo $row['images'];
```

I discovered that what I SHOULD be doing is PHP code:

```
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES (CURRENT_DATE,'$image')");
```

and put the markup in its proper place:

```
echo "<img src='";
echo $row['images'];
echo "' />";
```

I think you can implement a similar strategy to your code to **fix the problem.**

NOTE: mySQL is now depreciated, but you can use this technique with it's successors, mySQLi and PDO.